# How can I concurrently auto update file location of my excel worksheet

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-framework-version

How can I con-currently auto update file location of my excel workheet while write data from serial port and same excel sheet to read and plot the chart.

Also I want to make use of Microsoft database access nd csv to store same data on it.

I tried to use " Using excel= Microsoft.office.interpol.Excel" package and generated a new excel worksheet. I have designated folder where I store this file on fetching data from serial monitor.
But I also defining a path of the file while I start to read the excel worksheet. But since I everytime generate new excel worksheet. I need to update filepath while reading in code. I acutally want to automatically fetch the filepath of recently generated worksheet.

I am expecting a code solution where only single folder with a recently generated file location is accessed through code which can to written and read to plot chart.

Comment: I don't know hat you mean fetching generated worksheet. I mean if you generated then you must know where it is. but In case you don't you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-8.0 . Which can watch for file created or updated and get the path.